# Images not updating without flushing cache

Tags: html, image, caching

When I upload a new image to my site it seems to not show me the updated image without first clearing my browser cache.

I'm pretty sure this isn't normal behaviour but I have no idea how to fix it, and it's causing me to pull my hair out.

Comment: What HTTP headers are sent with the image? They're almost certainly telling the browser to cache the image for a while. Try a hard refresh instead of emptying the cache.

Comment: Do you want the image to change constantly for all users of the website, or do you simply want to disable caching temporarily for the purposes of developing the website?

Comment: Matt - I don't know what headers are being sent, I'm designing front end.
I just want images to refresh when I refresh the browser, or users refresh it.
Shouldn't the cache be refreshed with a cmd + R?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think image caching is a normal browser behavior. It makes sense: images are large, and don't change very often. If you need to refresh an image because you are developing the website, but you expect the image to be unchanging in the future, I recommend disabling caching in your browser, temporarily, while you develop the website.

#### To disable cache temporarily for development purposes in Chrome:

`wrench/tools/developer tools/gear icon (bottom right)/check "Disable cache"`

If you need the image to change constantly for the production version of the website, you can configure your server to tell browsers not to cache the page.

Comment: Well, as you say, caching behaviour can be controlled through sending the right headers on server side; sending the right combination of headers will make the browser respond to a reload without you having to clear the cache.